# ReactJS rendering a component in a specific DIV element

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to render a component generated by a route; however, I need the component rendered to a specific element:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-feather-yh1bt

Clicking on the "Log It In" link on the home component will route you to the "/Login" component.  In this component - clicking on any of the "Window" links renders the component correctly; however, I need the component rendered to the "logincontainer" elementID.  How do I pull that off?  Thanks All!

Comment: can you explain a bit more what is expected?

Comment: When I click on a Window link, I need the associated component rendered inside the "logincontainer" element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move

```
 <Route path="/Login/Win1" component={win1} />
 <Route path="/Login/Win2" component={win2} />
 <Route path="/Login/Win3" component={win3} />
```

Inside the `logincontainer` div.

like this

```
  <div
      id="logincontainer"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "Aqua", width: "100%", height: "200px" }}
    >
      <Route path="/Login/Win1" component={win1} />
      <Route path="/Login/Win2" component={win2} />
      <Route path="/Login/Win3" component={win3} />
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need wrap them in a <Router>?

Comment: No, see my update. (the `<Route>` needs to be inside a `<Router>` but not directly so it is good because of the parent is wrapped  inside a `<Router>`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use react portals for that.
More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

```
render() {
  // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the component into `domNode`.
  // `domNode` is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM.
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <MyComponent />,
    domNode
  );
}
```